# Prove that a map $f: C\rightarrow D$ between two chain complexes induces a map $f_*:H_d(C) \rightarrow H_d(D),\ \forall d\geq0$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Prove that a map $f: C\rightarrow D$ between two chain complexes induces a map $f_*:H_d(C) \rightarrow H_d(D),\ \forall d\geq0$

I know that for $d\geq0$, the $d^{th}$ homology group of C is $H_d(C)=ker(\delta)/im(\delta)$ but I do not know how to show that a map of chain complexes induces a map.

Answer (score 1):

You need to show that $f$ takes cycles to cycles and boundaries to boundaries.  But this is a consequence of $\partial\circ d = \partial \circ f$ ($\partial$ is the boundary map on each complex).

So if $c$ is a cycle in $C$, $f_*([c]) = [f(c)]$ is well-defined.